# Getting Conversation Members causes bad request (Microsoft Graph)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get information from 1:1 conversations between another user and I. Some users return a conversation which has a conversation type of: "groupChat" and a conversation ID that starts with the prefix "19:". Getting the list of members within conversations with that prefix works fine. Some users however, return a conversation type of "personal" and a conversation ID that starts with the prefix "a:". This is causing issues and a Bad Request when trying to get the Conversation Members using the Microsoft Graph API (beta). How can we use that conversation ID to get the members within that conversation?

Edit (12/07/2020):
I am getting these Conversation IDs by using the Messaging Extension on Microsoft Teams while focused on the conversation that I need the ID from.

Comment: Just wanted to check if you are still facing any issues. Here is how you can [retrieve conversation chatId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#-retrieve-the-conversation-chatid).

Comment: Yes I am @Wajeed-MSFT I keep getting the wrong Conversation ID. Check the comments under Hilton's answer for more detail

Comment: We're using Messaging Extension to retrieve a 1:1's conversation ID

Comment: @Rafael - For 1:1 chat between user and Bot conversation Id is encrypted and you can't use it to call Graph API. For 1:1 you can get the user information in the bot context - turncontext.from.id.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT This is for a messaging extension compose box action in a 1:1 between a user and another user. Not user : bot. Random users return a valid conversation ID, others don't.

Comment: When you invoke the Message extension from the Group chat then you will receive the conversation is starting with "19:" which is used to fetch the conversation members.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT The problem is sometimes I don't receive 19: I receive a: instead. Some users are fine, but others are not.

Comment: Are you not receiving the id stating with "19:" when user sends a message from group chat to bot?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I am not getting the id "19:" when the user executes a command from the Compose Box. I am getting "a:"

Comment: Is user is invoking the Message Extension from group/team? Or user is invoking the Message extension Personal chat?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT The user is invoking the message extension in a 1:1 chat with another user.

Comment: I have tested the scenario. when user invokes the message extension from in 1:1 chat the type is group and getting the id as "19:" and when user invokes the ME from bot:user then the is "a:" as it is personal chat. This is by design.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT The problem is, that some 1:1 chat is not returning the type as group, but rather as personal. I am unable to get 19: on every 1:1 conversation with another user.

Comment: Could you please drop a mail to microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Will do so, can I also provide a video?

Comment: @Rafael did you ever end up solving this issue?

Comment: I have not, @Kobe . I am going to submit a recording of this issue soon.

Comment: @Rafael did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Kobe I have not and I will return to this issue soon. I had other priorities to take care of.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this yet, but I think what you might be needing is the 'list **Chat** Members' operation. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) for more. Note that it is a beta-only operation for now, so be aware of the risk of something changing.

Comment: That is exactly what we're using and that's the problem we're having in the question. prefixes a: conversation IDs are not working. Bad request

Comment: Ah, I see now - I thought were using the Team members endpoint. Out of interest, do both types come back when you call `GET /me/chats` ?

Comment: When I do the call using GET /me/chats/{id}/members using the conversation ID that starts with "19:" it works fine, I get all members (the conversation type is "groupChat" for that prefix), but when I try to use a conversation ID that starts with "a:" (conversation type is "personal") it gives bad request

Comment: sure, but are both of those types of chats coming back from /me/chats ?

Comment: When I do GET /me/chats though, only all the conversations with ID starting "19:" comes back, I never see any other starting prefix

Comment: Where are you getting these others from then (the ones staring "a:")?

Comment: It's random. Some users in a 1:1 conversation come out with 19: prefix, others come with that a: prefix.

Comment: could it be that those are external or something like that?

Comment: Nope. These are all contacts within my organization. I am using Microsoft Teams Messaging extension within my organization to get these Conversation IDs using the Bot Framework SDK.

Comment: I noticed one thing. When opening Teams on the browser, I can see all 1:1 conversations look normal at the URL with the 19: prefix. But at random some users may have that a: prefix when returning the conversation ID with the Bot Framework SDK

Comment: what about if you get the conversation Ids using Graph (not sure how you're using the Bot framework SDK to get those, if the bot is not part of conversation)

Comment: I am using Message Extension to execute a command from the Bot Menu when I am focused on a conversation. The bot then gets all the information in TurnContext and I look at the Activity for the Conversation

Comment: I presume you're getting conversation Id from the Activity in that case, just to be clear?

Comment: Activity.Conversation.Id , Yeah that would be correct.